# Specific literature style required (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I would have a question regarding a specific literature style that I need to adapt manually but cannot figure out properly.

I am using Overleaf-online in conjunction with Mendeley. Hence, I have all my papers, etc. in Mendeley and synchronize them directly with Overleaf. Here, are the questions that I have:

1. When I change the citation style (e.g. journal) in Mendeley, I have the impression that this affects also the citation style in Overleaf/Latex, is that correct? I know it should not but maybe fields are named different in the bibtex file?
2. Regardless of the Mendeley citation style, how can I prepare both my in-text as well as bibliography format properly? This is what I have so far as the commands in the bibtex environment:

```
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,uniquename=init,giveninits=true,doi=true,url=false,maxbibnames=9]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
% \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{references.bib} % The filename of the bibliography
```

Here are the problems I am facing:

For in-text citation style:

1. I need an ampersand (&) between only two authors, e.g. Meier & Fischer, 2018. When there are more than two authors (meaning starting from three), it should become "et al., 2020" = "Fischer et al., 2020".
2. I would need to add the comma after the author's names.
3. I do have several papers that feature the exact same names but different years. How do I adapt these first two rules for them as well? Or is this not possible because it would contradict uniqueness?
4. There are authors that have middle names, which are abbreviated, and sometimes these middle and first names are written in the text. How can I avoid this? Example: "Neff, 2020 has shown that..." but sometimes it says "Neff, H., 2018 has concluded on...". I do not want to manually edit all authors and make them the same. I guess Mendeley/Biblatex recognizes them as if they were two different persons, when in fact they aren't. Some solutions I found just suggested editing them manually but I have more than 2'000 authors. This would be a horrendous task...

For the bibliography style:
With some papers, I encounter the problem that some names of the authors are mentioned but then after XYZ number of authors, it just becomes "et al.". I have no idea why and tried to figure out if this happens after 4, 5 or more but there is no structure behind it, as far as I have seen. However, all full names are supplied in the bibtex file. For instance, in one paper, the same author plus 3 more are written with their full last name, abbreviated first name but in a different paper with more authors, it just becomes "et al" after X authors? Hence, my question is how can I display ALL authors in the bibliography with their full last name, and initial of their first name(s), followed by their year, title, journal/book? There are four papers though, that feature more than 1'000 authors, which is why I supplied the "9" option in the code below to become "et al." However, as mentioned above, there is no structure as some papers just write "et al" in the bibliography after 3 authors for no particular reason!?

Maybe you have an idea what is wrong with my citation style?
Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
Max

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. That makes it easier to write a good answer to your question and the question (and answer) become much more relevant for other people as well. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. You may also want to turn the code snippet shown so far into a fully compilable example document. If your question depends on your specific `.bib` entries, you should also share the relevant entries of your `Literatur.bib` with us.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. It was an issue with the maxbibnames, which I adapted correctly (latter problem). For the first problem, I would need your help on how to implement an ampersand between two names, and if there are more than 2 names, how this can be abbreviated to "et al.". Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to focus only on the remaining issue. Please also include a compilable example document (starting with `\documentclass` and containing `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) that shows what you have so far and what you are trying to do.